# Scheme quicksort - Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure (1 2 3 4 5 7 ...)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, quicksort

I just started learning Scheme (Petite Chez Scheme) and as a challenge to myself I'm trying to implement quicksort. However I get the following exception when I run it:

```
Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure (1 2 3 4 5 7 ...)
```

Here's my Scheme session from Emacs:

```
Petite Chez Scheme Version 8.4
Copyright (c) 1985-2011 Cadence Research Systems

> (define (set a i k)
    (define (reduce-list a i n)
      (if(= i n)
     a
     (reduce-list (cdr a) (+ i 1) n)))
    (if(= i 0)
       (cons k (cdr a))
       (let ((b (cons k (reduce-list a 0 (+ i 1)))))
     (let push-front ((lst b) (original-list a) (n (- i 1)))
       (if(<= n 0)
          (cons (list-ref original-list 0) lst)
          (push-front (cons (list-ref original-list n) lst) original-list (- n 1)))))))

(define (swap lst i j)
    (let ((a (list-ref lst i))
      (b (list-ref lst j)))
      (set (set lst i b) j a)))

(define (partition a i j r)
    (cond [(= j r) (cons (+ i 1) (swap a (+ i 1) j))]
      [(<= (list-ref a j) (list-ref a r)) (partition (swap a j (+ i 1)) (+ i 1) (+ j 1) r)]
      [else (partition a i (+ j 1) r)]))

(define (quicksort a p r)
    (if(< p r)
       (begin(
          (let* ((c (partition a (- p 1) p r))
            (q (car c))
            (b (quicksort (cdr c) p (- q 1))))
        (quicksort b (+ q 1) r))))
       a))

> (define lst (list 1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5))
> (define n (length lst))
> (trace quicksort)
(quicksort)
> (quicksort lst 0 (- n 1))
|(quicksort (1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5) 0 8)
| (quicksort (1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9) 0 3)
| |(quicksort (1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9) 0 2)
| | (quicksort (1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9) 0 1)
| | |(quicksort (1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9) 0 0)
| | |(1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9)
| | |(quicksort (1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9) 2 1)
| | |(1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9)
Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure (1 2 3 4 5 7 ...)
>
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the

```
begin
```

in quicksort. When

```
(quicksort b (+ q 1) r)
```

eventually returns a (which is actually b in the parent quicksort), then the let* block reduces from

```
(define (quicksort a p r)
  (if(< p r)
     (begin(
            (let* ((c (partition a (- p 1) p r))
                   (q (car c))
                   (b (quicksort (cdr c) p (- q 1))))
              (quicksort b (+ q 1) r)))) 
     a))
```

to

```
(define (quicksort a p r)
  (if(< p r)
     (begin
        (b)) ;this is the cause of the error 
     a))
```

And since b is a list, trying to call it fails with an error. If you remove the begin, the let block will behave as you intend.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Works perfectly now! I guess I misunderstood the use of begin!

Answer (score 0):

In quicksort remove the `(begin(` and the last `)` on the `(quicksort b (+ q 1) r)` line.

The `(` after the `begin`, and the `)` on the quicksort call line are applying the result of that second quicksort call.

This is because it is the last expression in the body of the `let*`, so it is the let*'s return value. The list it returns is the list that is definitely not a procedure.

Also, all lets have an implicit begin in them.

For example

```
(let ([a 1] [b 2] [c 3])
  (set! b 3)
  a
  b)
```

Would return 3 (the plain a call is a worthless and its value is ignored)

And it is equivalent to the following code:

```
(let ([a 1] [b 2] [c 3])
  (begin
     (set! b 3)
     a
     b))
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. Why would you ever need a begin statement then?

Comment: some structures do not have implicit begin, like if

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the answer to your question, I'd like to clarify something missing from the other answers, that will hopefully help you and/or others with their understanding of `(begin ())`.

I most commonly use `(begin ())` as you did in `(if ())` statements because the function only has two slots after the conditional.

Thus, the `(begin ())` becomes useful when intending to evaluate multiple statements for one or both sides of the conditional "split in the road", *per se*.

An example:

```
(do ([i 0 (+ i 1)]) [(< i 10)]
  (if (= (% i 2) 1)
    (printf 'odd)
    (begin
      (printf 'even)
      'even)))
```

Above I only use `(begin ())` when I want *Chez* to perform two separate actions if the number `i` is even. When `i` is odd I don't need a begin statement and we can carry on.

Just a note, *Chez Scheme* will evaluate the contents of the begin statement in order. In *[The Scheme Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:h2)*, it says near the bottom of the page:

> "The syntactic form begin [...] evaluates its subexpressions in
>   sequence from left to right and returns the value of the last
>   subexpression, like the body of a let or lambda expression."