# Why is (begin) valid in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have tested in Racket and Chez Scheme and found `(begin)` is acceptable while `(define a (begin))` is not. For example with Racket I got

```
> (begin)
> (define a (begin))
; stdin:56:10: begin: empty form not allowed
```

And my question is why is `(begin)` allowed at all? Is there any specific reason/intuition for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form begin has two purposes.

```
1. To sequence the evaluation of expressions 
2. To "splice" sequences together (used by macros)
```

The first one is what is used most often:

```
(begin e0 e1 ...)
```

will evaluate the expressions e0 e1 ... in order.

The second is used when a macro expands to multiple definitions and/or expressions.

As an example, the following

```
(begin
   (begin d1 e1 d2 d3)
   (begin)
   e2
   ...)
```

will be flattened by the macro expander into:

```
(begin d1 e1 d2 d3 e2 ...)
```

Now to the question "Why is (begin) allowed at all?". If `begin` was used for purpose 1 (sequencing) then an empty `begin` could be disallowed. For purpose 2 (splicing) it is very convenient to use `(begin)` as the result of a macro that does nothing. Consider a macro `(debug expression)` that either expands into `expression` (when debugging is enabled) or into `(begin)` when debugging is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44835725/5544472) about `(begin ())` is another acceptable reason to use begin in `(if () )` statements.