# In Scheme, what is the returned value of `(begin)`?

Tags: compiler-construction, scheme, expression-evaluation, language-implementation, chez-scheme

I know that `(begin expr1 expr2 ...)` will evaluate all of the expressions and will return the last one evaluated.

I found that in Chez Scheme it's allowed to use `begin` without expressions like so: `(begin)`. I'm using Chez Scheme as part of my studies. When I write in the console `(begin)` it does not send a syntax error it just displays nothing as if I was getting `void`.

**My question is, what will be returned then?**

I thought it was the void object that you can get by running `(void)`.
However, when I tested it I realized it is not.

I'm studying Chez Scheme as part of a compiler course I'm taking and I need to implement a part of a compiler that can handle the special word `begin`. So I need to know why is this even possible and what this function returns.

EDIT:

I'm adding [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359441/why-is-begin-valid-in-scheme) regarding this topic. 
I wasn't able to fully understand the answer. Plus, he hasn't mentioned the return type.

Comment: If you're implementing part of a compiler, your definition of the meaning of the language forms should come from the specification, not from the existing behavior. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the question is confusing different uses of `begin`. If you look at [R6RS section 11.4.7](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.4.7) about `begin`, it is used in two different ways: 1) with 0 or more "forms", in which case the forms are syntactically "spliced" into the surrounding body just like if the `begin` wasn't there (I believe this is mainly useful when writing macros); and 2) with 1 or more expressions, in which case it evaluates the expressions in sequence and returns the result of the last one.

When you talk about "return value", you are talking about `(begin ...)` as an expression, but as an expression (the second form of `begin` above), it must take one or more expressions. An empty `(begin)` must be the first form of `begin`, which simply splices "nothing" (0 forms) into the surrounding body, but it isn't "evaluated" separately from the evaluation of the body as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the use of (begin) without expressions is not a procedure, rather a macro-like tool, and as such doesn't return any value and I can simply use it when it's allowed?

Comment: @PeNpeL: Well `begin` itself isn't a procedure; it's a special form of the language. But basically, yes, `(begin)` is not a use of the expression form of `begin`, and it isn't an expression by itself. If your compiler doesn't need to support complicated macros, maybe you can ignore the form-splicing form of `begin` for now.